# Can't access parent attribute in inherited Python class

Tags: python, inheritance

This is my parent class,

```
class BaseResource:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        fmt = '[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(message)s] [--> %(pathname)s [%(process)d]:]'
        logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=logging.DEBUG)

    def log(self, msg):
        self.logger.debug(msg)
```

This is my inherited object,

```
class SendOTP(BaseResource):

    def __init__(self):
        super(BaseResource, self).__init__()

    def on_post(self, req, res):
        self.logger.log("[FAILURE]..unable to read from POST data")
```

This throws up the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'SendOTP' object has no attribute 'logger'
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/Xmp1b2

Comment: If this is python3, you could simplify the `super` call to `super().__init__()`

Comment: @melpomene imho, call on_post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `super(SendOTP, self)`, not `super(BaseResource, self)`.

Also, if this is Python 3, you can simplify it to just `super()`; if Python 2, you also need to change the declaration of `BaseResource` to

```
class BaseResource(object):
```

to get a new-style class.

Comment: This  worked but just curious, ```class BaseResource(object)``` is the old Python 2 style, right?

Comment: But now I get the following error, ```TypeError: log() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'```

Comment: So I guess this is an additional question, I'm trying to call a method from the super and I'm passing in the correct argument and still getting an error.

Comment: @MelissaStewart: [Read the docs for `Logger.log`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.log)

Answer (score 2):

If it is **python 3** you have to use: 
`Super()._init_()`

instead of `super(BaseResource, self).__init__()`

***and***

`super().log("[FAILURE]..unable to read")`

instead of `self.logger.log("[FAILURE]..unable to read")`

If it is **python 2** you have to use:
`BaseResource.__init__(self)`

instead of `super(BaseResource, self).__init__()`

***and***

`self.log("[FAILURE]..unable to read")`

instead of `self.logger.log("[FAILURE]..unable to read")`

Answer (score 1):

In super you should put your class type

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             print("hi")

>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(B, self).__init__()

>>> class C(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(A, self).__init__()

>>> B()
hi
<__main__.B object at 0x0000024F90141C88>

>>> C()
<__main__.C object at 0x0000024F90141D30>
```